# GraphQL: Error: Must provide Document

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, graphql-js, apollo-server

**UPDATE: apollo has updated code and docs so issue is irrelevant now**

**Intended outcome**

start apollo-server-express using the following snippet from https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-tutorial-kit.

```
import express from 'express';
import { graphqlExpress, graphiqlExpress } from 'apollo-server-express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import schema from './data/schema';

const GRAPHQL_PORT = 3000;

const graphQLServer = express();

graphQLServer.use('/graphql', bodyParser.json(), graphqlExpress({ schema }));
graphQLServer.use('/graphiql', graphiqlExpress({ endpointURL: '/graphql' }));

graphQLServer.listen(GRAPHQL_PORT, () => console.log(`GraphiQL is now running on http://localhost:${GRAPHQL_PORT}/graphiql`));
```

**Actual Outcome:**

In any implementation of apollo-server-express, using docs, using https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-tutorial-kit, etc. I receive the follow stack trace over and over again:

```
Error: Must provide document
    at invariant (~/node_modules/graphql/jsutils/invariant.js:18:11)
    at Object.validate (~/node_modules/graphql/validation/validate.js:58:34)
    at doRunQuery (~/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/runQuery.js:80:38)
    at ~/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/runQuery.js:20:54
    at <anonymous>
```

How to reproduce the issue:

```
git clone https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-tutorial-kit.git
cd apollo-tutorial-kit
yarn/npm i
npm start
```

Comment: 4 months ago, i thinks is very old for apollo, that keep changing

Comment: The starter kit works fine. That sounds like an error you are getting in response to a request you're making. Usually that error is thrown when the request body is malformed or the `Content-Type: application/json` header is missing. You should update your question to include how you're attempting to make the request to the server.

Comment: After clearing my npm cache && node_modules, I got it to work! Thanks guys

Answer (score 9):

In my case I was getting this error because I wasn't using the correct key in my request to the graphql server.

I was sending a `mutation` request and I thought the key in the object needed to be `"mutation"` but it turns out both query and mutation requests use the key `"query"`.

```
xhr.open('POST', '/graphql');
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
  query: mutationString,
}));
```

Answer (score -1):

I was using JQuery Ajax for HTTP Post Request to graphql server (apollo-server-express) and getting this error while querying for mutation. The reason was same as described by [spencer.sm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3498950/spencer-sm). To help other googlers, I am pasting here complete method-

```
(function() {
    globals.makeGraphQLRequest('graphql', {
        query: `query($email: String!) {
            profile(email: $email) {
                id mobile name email dob gender
            }
        }`,
        variables: {
            email: 'varunon9@gmail.com'
        }
    }, function successCallback(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });

    globals.makeGraphQLRequest('graphql', {
        query: `mutation($email: String!) {
            updateUser(email: $email) {
                email
            }
        }`,
        variables: {
            email: 'varunon9@gmail.com'
        }
    }, function successCallback(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
}());
```

makeGraphQLRequest-

```
globals.makeGraphQLRequest = function(url, params, successCallback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: 'post',
        data: params,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            successCallback(response);
        },
        error: globals.ajaxErrorHandler
    });
}
```